# Is there a way to define a contract to implement a method with no parameter restrictions (see explanation)?

Tags: java

I understand what interfaces and abstract classes are, but I don't know how to get the following functionality; *if it's possible, that is*.  I have a bunch of classes which are each going to have a `validate()` method. Each method may take different parameters.  For example, we could have classes with the following methods:

```
boolean validate();
boolean validate(Block[]);
boolean validate(BlockSet[]);
...
```

So, basically I want to know if I can use an interface or abstract class, or something else, to define a contract to have a method with a given name and return type implemented, but no restrictions on the set of parameters. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with validate(Object... args), but it's worth questioning whether you really want to.  Interfaces and Abstract Classes are useful so that you can group a bunch of similar objects together, and have implementations do different things with the same operation.  It seems to me that you wouldn't be able to call this method without knowing what the underlying implementation is, and therefore there is no reason to abstract them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using varargs in an interface:

`boolean validate(Object... args)` or

'boolean validate(Block... blocks)`

if the `Blocks` are always a collection, use their supertype:

```
boolean validate(Collection<Block> blocks)
```

But then you may need to use some casts. Not best option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want method to take any number pf parameters then you can use Varargs but if you want it to change Type also then its not feasible.

Also what you want to achieve is find a separate way of method overloading, but for that you will have to explicitly specify the methods.